# Sails.js override response methods

Tags: sails.js

I'm using SailsJS 0.9.8 and I would like to add some information to each API response if the response should go to a websocket.

The reason I want to do this is that the application makes use of websockets a lot via socketIO and when using the send() and json() methods of the response object the status code is not added to the json that is sent to the socket which is otherwise available if sending via http. I could just add the status to the json before sending but it would get messy so I would like to do it some other way.

Some of the response methods, like badRequest() and serverError() etc, do add the expected status code but send() and json() do not, even if I give it as a parameter. Is it possible to change this behaviour?

P.S. I did look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528352/how-can-i-wrap-each-api-response-into-a-standard-reply-object-in-sailsjs/23528687#23528687) which is basically the same as my question but the chosen answer didn't work for me, i copied the source files for badRequest and put it in api/responses/ and simply added a printout but it never showed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is supported in sails.js 0.10.x: http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Custom-Responses